# Rails 3 task scopes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am working on a simple rails 3 todo application and I am trying to filter the app by completed tasks and none completed task but whenever I try calling a scope I get the error message.

```
undefined method `completed' for #<Array:0x007fe8420d0e58>
```

task.rb

```
scope :completed , where(:completed => true)
scope :incomplete , where(:finished => false)
```

index.html.erb

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Finished</th>
    <th>User</th>
  </tr>
  <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= task.name %><%= button_to "complete", complete_task_path(task.id)%></td>
    <td><%= task.description %></td>
    <td><%= task.finished %></td>
    <td><%= task.user_id %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', task %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', task, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<%= content_tag :h2, "Stuff Ive done" %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <% @tasks.completed.each do |task| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= task.name %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

task_controller.rb

```
def complete
 @task = Task.find(params[:task_id])
 @task.completed = true
 @task.save
 redirect_to task_path
end
```

routes.rb

```
match "tasks/:id/complete" => "task#complete", :as => :complete_task
```

Any reasons why rails is giving me this error?

Comment: Where is `@tasks` defined? I see an `@task` but no `@tasks`.

Comment: @muistooshort should I replace task with tasks?

Comment: `@tasks` is defined somewhere or you'd be getting a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`. Something is creating `@tasks` as an array rather than the ActiveRecord::Relation that you're expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by looking at your view (index.html.erb), in one place, you are treating as a relation.

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
```

Later in the code, you are trying to access it as a single object.

```
<% @tasks.completed.each do |task| %>
```

Since you are seeing the error on the second instance, you need to access 'completed' as in:

```
<% @tasks.completed.each do |task| %>
  <% completed = task.completed %>
     <% completed.each do |com| %>
```

Does this make sense?